# Trying to program a scientific calculator in java but can't get the exponent button to work

Tags: java, calculator, pow, exponent

I'm trying to program a scientific calculator with a GUI in java and have been able to do everything so far except for the exponent button (x^y).

Here's what I have for the button click event right now but it doesn't work because I can't figure out how to take in two values while only pressing the button one time.

```
private void btnExponentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            double x = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tfdDisplay.getText()));
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            double y = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tfdDisplay.getText()));
        }
        tfdDisplay.setText(null);
    }
    double ops = Math.pow(x, y);
    tfdDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(ops));
}
```

I would like it to take in the value that is currently in the textfield, then have the user click the exponent button, then take in the next value they put in as the actual exponent value, then calculate the answer when they click the "=" button.

I've looked online and found a video that shows how to make a scientific calculator with an exponent button but when I follow his method of coding the button, it does not work correctly. Instead, it just squares what is inside the textfield, rather than letting the user put in their own exponent.

Here's a picture of what the calculator actually looks like for reference.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXLch.png)

Thanks in advance!

edit:
Here is what I have programmed for the "=" button.

```
String answer;
        secondnum = Double.parseDouble(tfdDisplay.getText());
        if(operations == "+")
        {
            result = firstnum + secondnum;
            answer = String.format("%.2f", result);
            tfdDisplay.setText(answer);
        }
        else if(operations == "-")
        {
            result = firstnum - secondnum;
            answer = String.format("%.2f", result);
            tfdDisplay.setText(answer);
        }
        else if(operations == "*")
        {
            result = firstnum * secondnum;
            answer = String.format("%.2f", result);
            tfdDisplay.setText(answer);
        }
        else if(operations == "/")
        {
            result = firstnum / secondnum;
            answer = String.format("%.2f", result);
            tfdDisplay.setText(answer);
        }
```

Should I add this to the "=" button?

```
else if(operations == "^")
        {
            result = Math.pow(firstnum, secondnum);
            answer = String.format("%.2f", result);
            tfdDisplay.setText(answer);
        }
```

Comment: What's the point of the for-loop? It's creating the scoping issues you're having with no benefit. This code shouldn't even run unless I'm missing something. You're also making `x` and `y` the same thing since you're pulling their values from the same element. Did you mean for `y` to be set by a different element than `tfdDisplay`?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how text fields work. It won't wait for user input, so your first value will get parsed, then the second value will always be empty because you clear it at the end of the loop. As a hint, you describe how to solve this problem in your question - you need to only get the first value when the exponent button is pressed and the second when the equals button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to solve my problem.

Here is what I put inside the button click event:

```
    private void btnExponentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        firstnum = Double.parseDouble(tfdDisplay.getText());
        tfdDisplay.setText(null);
        operations = "^";
    }
```

and here is what I added to the "=" button click event:

```
else if(operations == "^")
{
    result = Math.pow(firstnum, secondnum);
    answer = String.format("%.2f", result);
    tfdDisplay.setText(answer);
}
```

Thank you Obicere!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you hit the buttons `digit`, then `^`, then `digit` and then `=` and at this point you have, for example, `2^4` as text in the `tfdDisplay` element. Then what you should do is split the text and get the two values, like this:

```
private void btnExponentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // Notice the double backslash, it's used because split wants a regular
    // expression, and ^ means the beginning of the string in regular
    // expressions, so you have to escape it using a backslash. The other
    // one is needed because you should escape backslashes on strings to use
    // as is
    String parts[] = tfdDisplay.getText().split("\\^");
    double x = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
    double y = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
    double ops = Math.pow(x, y);
    tfdDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(ops));
}
```